# Animation for Game on Android

Tags: android, animation

I built a typical side-scroller helicopter game.  I'm having some trouble with the animation lagging on newer devices.  There really is no point in providing the code.  Explaining it will suffice.

The game uses the Kilobolt Framework.  The life cycle of the game is constant loop that just redraws the screen over and over, based on the variables set along the way.  Meaning, whatever state/position something is in, it gets drawn.  So it's very easy to simply set the x/y on any number of objects and just let the thing run.  The screen is drawn in the framebuffer and uses no XML at all.
There are 4500 tiles that get updated on the X every time the screen redraws.  Which isn't really a whole lot.
I've already dropped all my graphic assets down to PNG-8 with no Transparency, to remove all that overhead.

I have no performance issues, in that the game plays great, with no memory leaks, errors, or other crashes...

The only issue I have is that the newer the device, the more the game lags intermittently.  By that I mean, it runs at a constant speed for a few seconds, then drags for a second or so.  But this only happens on newer devices.  Anything running KitKat or lower runs 100% with no lags.  Anything higher has troubles.

I'm hoping someone out there has run into something like this.  Is there something I can set in the manifest to force it to run at a lower level? Currently it's set to target 14, 4.0 Ice Cream Sammich, with a minimum of 8.

This is not a promotion, but I'm [including the Play link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.klawton.coptergame&hl=en) so you can see for yourself.

Comment: Are you creating and recreating many objects that would be garbage collected? Consider using an object pool.

Comment: Also , without code , i suspect all of the answers here would be simply conjecture... As a result , many of them may find a place in the comments section.

Comment: No new objects are created or destroyed.  When a tile moves off the screen, it is moved to the other side of the set.  Anything that is made to disappear is simply replaced with a blank graphic.  So the number of objects being tracked never changes.  I did this on purpose so that the load on the CPU never changes.

Comment: @worlboss...  If someone can provide a comment that steers me the right way, I will happily request they make it an answer so I can award the big green check mark.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No.  In fact, I ran a few tests...  Even with the scrolling turned completely off, and just having a single object flying around the screen, I get the exact same lag.  It has nothing to do with taxing the system.  It has something to do with this program (or any written the same way) not being able to take precedence over other processes.

Comment: If someone has some idea how to get the app precedence that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are clearing the whole screen it simply declines the performance instead use postInvalidate which will only redraw the area which is changed not the whole of the screen which significantly improves the performance . You can refer this
[link](https://forums.ouya.tv/discussion/2485/2d-game-loops-performance-ondraw-with-postinvalided-vs-runnable-surfaceview)

Comment: What that tells me is one thing I hadn't considered.  Double to Int conversion.  The tiles are incremented as Int.  No problem there.  But the copter increments on double, then draws on int.  I wonder if that conversion is the whole problem.  I will have to look into that as my first step.

Comment: Are you suggesting (also) that I check if a tile is in the viewable area before bothering to draw it?  Because currently it will draw the object if it's at x=1 or x=27,000 (meaning it's WAY off the screen.)

Comment: I think the problem outlined in this answer would result in consistently slow drawing... But I believe that the question is pointing to regular drops in performance... I had this problem once in a JavaScript game I made. It was fixed by removing the game logic from the main thread, and by removing the games" physics " from being dependent on a change in time. I did this because other applications in the background caused intermittent frame rate drops.

Comment: Yes exactly what I meant to say is draw only that amount which is required that would improve the performance a lot . postinvalidate is the part which will do this redrawing of frame

Comment: I have come to find that it's not because I'm taxing the system too hard.  If I have s single object flying around the screen, I get the exact same lag.  And I can't stress enough that this is ONLY on newer devices.  My old phones and tablets, all run the thing perfectly.  So what is different with the newer devices?